# How do I make this window when .call(this) from a commonJS module

Tags: javascript, commonjs

I am using Webpack to package my dependency I am trying to load the method-combintator. The dependency looks like this...

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.3.1
(function() {
  var __slice = [].slice;

  this.before = function(decoration) {
    return function(base) {
      return function() {
        decoration.apply(this, arguments);
        return base.apply(this, arguments);
      };
    };
  };
  ...
}).call(this);
```

Then I include in my TS file like...

```
require("method-combinators/lib/method-combinators.js");
```

When I breakpoint on the inside function I notice `this != window`. If I try to add...

```
require.bind(window);
```

I get

> Critical dependencies: 20:0-7 require function is used in a way in
>   which dependencies cannot be statically extracted

What is the right way to do this?

**Update**

```
> this
Object {}
> window
Window {...}
```

If I do

```
window['comb'] = require("method-combinators/lib/method-combinators.js");
```

It seems to work, but because this is legacy code it is really hard to search for all instances of after and begin.

**Update 2**

This kinda works...

```
var comb = require("method-combinators/lib/method-combinators.js");
window['after'] = comb.after;
window['before'] = comb.before;
```

Which is similar to the answer provided by @tcooc but the problem is I have to list out each function. For underscore I have something like this...

```
var s = require("underscore.string");
window['_'].mixin(s.exports());
```

But the problem here is comb does not have `exports`

**Update 3**

This was my final

```
var comb = require("method-combinators/lib/method-combinators.js");
window['_'].extend(window, comb);
```

Comment: Why does `this` need to equal `window`? The opposite should be true.

Comment: I need to add it to the window, otherwise I cannot call it like after(function(){}) I have to call it like var.after.function

Comment: Are you mixing JavaScript, CoffeeScript *and* TypeScript?!? You are a brave person :).

Comment: Haha thats wht I get from a legacy app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

commonjs modules, by design, do not access or modify to the global scope (or at least they shouldn't). The `this` variable in your code is referencing the exported value from that module, not `window`. The code is actually wrapped in something like (simplified for your use case):

```
// you want to load "method-combinator.js"
require('method-combinator.js');
// load "method-combinator.js" as "dependency()"
var exports = {};
dependency.call(exports);
```

Now whenever you try to load "method-combinator.js", `exports` is returned.

The correct way to use the dependency is:

```
var combinators = require('method-combinator.js');
```

If you wish to add all values of `combinators` to the `window`, assuming you have underscore:

```
_.extend(window, combinators);
// or if _ is somehow not resolving properly (for some reason?)
window._.extend(window, combinators);
```

Comment: @Jackie Updated answer. See last 2 paragraphs.

Comment: Sorry I need it on window not _ will this be done the same way. I also had a typo

Comment: nm I see I missed the extend

Comment: Accepted your answer and thank you so much I updated the question with my final code.